# Ошибка при установке APK Release

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk

Разрабатываю в Android Studio. Проблема в установке на Android <7. Минимальный SDK установлен в 21 (Android 5.0), но приложение ставится только на Android 7, ниже идет ошибка:

> Не удалось разобрать пакет установки.

Вот код build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.software.metilar.miuipro"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "MiuiPro-" + defaultConfig.versionName)
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/jsoup-1.10.3.jar')
    compile 'com.github.omadahealth:swipy:1.2.3@aar'
}
```

Пробовал скачать в SDK Manager инструменты для данных версий, все также. Пробовал уменьшать minSdkVersion, не помогает. Подскажите в чем проблема.

Comment: а на Android 6 тоже не ставится?

Comment: да, только на 7 ставит

Comment: я не уверен, но у меня есть подозрения, что это из-за Java 8

Comment: что предлагаете?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html проверьте используете ли вы, что-то из перечисленного в таблице `Supported Java 8 Language Features and APIs`, если да, то сначала попробуйте добавить в `gradle.properties` строку `android.enableDesugar=false`. Если это не поможет, то перепишите код, без использования Java8

Comment: Напишите, если это вам помогло, как ответ оформлю для других, ищущих ответ

Comment: то что в таблице не использую вроде, но при android.enableDesugar=false пишет ошибку, просит true. Может быть из-за того что установлена JDK8?

Comment: сомневаюсь если честно, а что будет если поставить JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

Comment: А откуда у вас  `buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'`, 27 вроде еще не вышла, у меня стоит `26.0.2`, при том, что у меня еще sdk 27 версия стоит.

Comment: @Iman, вышла, это 8.1

Comment: @Komdosh, изменил, на 7 андроиде установилось нормально, а на меньших пока что нет возможности проверить( как найду кого то, скажу результат

Comment: @Komdosh, это `stable` вышла или `beta`, если `stable` должна же была всем обнова придти не?

Comment: @Iman https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html stable, не всегда сразу приходит

Comment: @Komdosh, проблема остается

Comment: хм, ну можно ещё пересоздать проект или попробовать откатить версию buildTools

Comment: @Komdosh, обнаружил что debug версия ставится нормально, а release с подписью - не хочет. Где я туплю?

Comment: Удалите debug с устройства, потом ставьте release, если не поможет подключите к компу и посмотрите логи при попытке установки - должен же он  причину высказать.

Comment: При создании релизного АПК ставите 2 галочки в выборе подписи?

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych, 2, не помню как, но как то решил проблему и больше подобное не происходит